# How to add this in a function to callback of handleChange and componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

How to add this in a function to callback of handleChange and componentDidMount?

```
// callback from github api /api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}

const [repository, issues] = await Promise.all([
  api.get(`/repos/${repoName}`),
  api.get(`/repos/${repoName}/issues`, {
    params: {
      state: 'all', 
// I need change this by select options = all, closed and open (per example) 
     per_page: 5, 
    },
  }),
]);

// this define setState again in handleChange

this.setState({repository: repository.data,
issues: issues.data,
loading: false,
});


// Example: 

componentDidMount () {functionUP();};

handleChange () {functionUpAgain(with state from params = all, open or closed);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). It's not clear what you're asking here. Please update the question to add a [mcve] and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

well since you are using `await` your function needs to be `async`.

So something like

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  // callback from github api /api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}
  async fetchData(state = 'all') {
    const [repository, issues] = await Promise.all([
      api.get(`/repos/${repoName}`),
      api.get(`/repos/${repoName}/issues`, {
        params: {
          state,
          // I need change this by select options = all, closed and open (per example) 
          per_page: 5,
        },
      }),
    ]);
    // this define setState again in handleChange

    this.setState({
      repository: repository.data,
      issues: issues.data,
      loading: false,
    });
  }

  // Example: 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    const somestate = 'open'; // here you decide what state to pass to the fetchData
    this.fetchData(somestate);
  };

  render() {

  }
}
```

---

I cannot help with how to get the state to pass the `fetchData` since your code does not show where that might come from. But the example code allows to pass a parameter to the `fetchData` method which will passed to the API.

You also should consider refactoring that code so that `api.get(`/repos/${repoName}`)` is not called always (*since it looks like it uses no params and it would return the same data always*)